# Connected component Labeling in android

Tags: android, image-processing, components, labeling

I am creating an android app related to license plate extraction from an image. The algorithm that i am following to extract the license plate is based on Connected Component Labeling of objects(blob) in an image. In matlab i can easily perform CCL using bwlabel() but i cant find anything like bwlabel in android (eclipse IDE)

Is there some predefined method or any other way that can help me labeling the objects in an image in Android?

Comment: Implement it? Its a fairly simple recursive algorithm. [See this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Man, I am really bad at Java, but I created my own connected component labelling class. Use the TwoPass function:

```
public class ConnectedComponentsLabelling {
public static int[][] twoPass(int[][] matrix) {

    int nextLabel = 1;

    int rowLength = matrix.length;
    int columnLength = matrix[0].length;

    List<Set<Integer>> linked = new ArrayList<Set<Integer>>();
    int[][] labels = new int[rowLength][columnLength];

    //Primeiro Passo
    for (int row = 0; row < rowLength; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < columnLength; column++) {
            if (matrix[row][column] != 0) {
                int[] neibours = neibours(row, column, labels);
                if (neibours.length == 0) {
                    linked.add(new HashSet());
                    linked.get(nextLabel - 1).add(nextLabel);
                    labels[row][column] = nextLabel;
                    nextLabel += 1;
                } else {
                    Arrays.sort(neibours);
                    labels[row][column] = neibours[0];
                    for (int i = 0; i < neibours.length; i++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < neibours.length; j++) {
                            linked.get(neibours[i] - 1).add(neibours[j]);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    //Segundo Passo
    int[] vector = new int[nextLabel];
    for (int i= 0; i < nextLabel - 1; i++){
        vector[i] = Collections.min(linked.get(i), null);
    }

    for (int row = 0; row < rowLength; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < columnLength; column++) {
            if (matrix[row][column] != 0) {
                labels[row][column] = vector[labels[row][column] - 1];
            }
        }
    }
    return labels;
}

public static int[] neibours(int row, int column, int[][] matrix) {

    int[] neibours = {};
    int rowLength = matrix.length;
    int columnLength = matrix[0].length;


    if (row ==0 && column ==0) { return neibours;
    }
    else if (row == 0) {
        neibours = add_element(matrix[row][column - 1], neibours);
    } else if (column == 0) {
        neibours = add_element(matrix[row - 1][column], neibours);
    } else if ((row > 0) && (column > 0) && (column < columnLength - 1)) {
        neibours = add_element(matrix[row][column - 1], neibours);
        neibours = add_element(matrix[row - 1][column - 1], neibours);
        neibours = add_element(matrix[row - 1][column], neibours);
        neibours = add_element(matrix[row - 1][column + 1], neibours);
    } else if (row > 0 && column > 0) {
        neibours = add_element(matrix[row][column - 1], neibours);
        neibours = add_element(matrix[row - 1][column - 1], neibours);
        neibours = add_element(matrix[row - 1][column], neibours);
    }

    int[] neibours2 = {};
    for (int i = 0; i < neibours.length; i++) {
        if (neibours[i] != 0) {
            neibours2 = add_element(neibours[i], neibours2);
        }
    }
    return neibours2;
}

public static int max(int[] vector){
    int max = 0;
    for (int number = 0; number < vector.length; number++) {
        if (number > max){max = number;}
    }
    return max;
}

public static int[] areaCount(int[][] matrix){
    int[] vectorLabel = {};
    int[] vectorArea = {};
    int positionNew = 0;
    boolean teste;

    int rowLength = matrix.length;
    int columnLength = matrix[0].length;

    for (int row = 0; row < rowLength; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < columnLength; column++) {
            teste = true;

            for (int position = 0; position < vectorLabel.length; position++){
                if (vectorLabel[position] == matrix[row][column]) {positionNew = position; teste = false;}
            }
            if (teste){
                vectorLabel = add_element(matrix[row][column], vectorLabel);
                vectorArea = add_element(1, vectorArea);
            } else {
                vectorArea[positionNew] = vectorArea[positionNew] + 1;
            }
        }

    }

    return vectorArea;
}


public static int[] add_element(int element, int[] neibours) {
    neibours = Arrays.copyOf(neibours, neibours.length + 1);
    neibours[neibours.length - 1] = element;
    return neibours;
}
}
```

But i won't recommending using it because it is so slow... Better import OPENCV and use findCountours that is similar the idea but it is written in C.

I used it in one code to find the areas of different elements in a image:

```
List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
Mat imgMat = new Mat();    
List<Double> areasList = new ArrayList<Double>();

Imgproc.findContours(imgMat, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
 //matrix = ConnectedComponentsLabelling.twoPass(matrix);
 for (int idx = 0; idx < contours.size(); idx++) {
      Mat contour = contours.get(idx);
      double contourarea = Imgproc.contourArea(contour);
      areasList.add(contourarea);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Dinidiniz, I too ended up implementing it myself 4 years ago when the question was posed. It was quite slow.